# How to create jar dependencies?

Tags: java, eclipse

Project P2 depends on P1, but not vice versa. I want to make a jar out of P2. One way would be by exporting P2 to jar and then packaging P1 and other jars inside P2.

But, I want to do it without including P1 inside P2. How do I do it ?

Comment: just ensure that P1 jar is in P2 execution classpath.

Comment: @vfcosta - how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this question-answer: [How can I specify dependencies in the manifest file and then to include it into my .jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592115/how-can-i-specify-dependencies-in-the-manifest-file-and-then-to-include-it-into) I think it could be useful for your problem. In the way that you declare the dependency of P1 within P2 Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on P2 usage actually. Normally you just package P2 in jar, and declare the dependency in the documentation. Then when real usage occurs, someone will need to add both P1 & P2 in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Just package both as jars and deliver both. Deliver a batch file that runs your program p2 and  p1 on the classpath.

Why don't you consider using maven or gradle?